# mysql - select grouped values

Tags: mysql

I have this result set

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qb5g.jpg

and i'm trying to get entries as follow

get the ad_id of entries that have an attribute_id = 5 and value = 'Yamaha Mate V50' and attribute_id = 6 and value = 2012

i've tried stuff like

```
SELECT ad_id FROM value WHERE attribute_id = 5 && value = 'Yamaha Mate V50' && attribute_id = 6 && value = '2012'
```

this gives an empty result set

and if i did this

```
SELECT ad_id FROM value WHERE attribute_id = 5 && value = 'Yamaha Mate V50' || attribute_id = 6 && value = '2012'
```

i get ad_id = 1 and 3 which is good however i also get ad_id = 2 which is logical because it does have this condition (attribute_id = 6 && value = '2012')

so what should i do to select only the ad_ids that fulfill both conditions

(attribute_id = 5 && value = 'Yamaha Mate V50') "AND" (attribute_id = 6 && value = '2012')

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ad_id FROM value
WHERE (attribute_id,value) IN ((5,'Yamaha Mate V50'),(6,'2012'))
GROUP BY ad_id
HAVING count(*)=2
```

Comment: hellow @Michael Krelin - hacker your answer was good but i've faced another dead end the thing is i want not to extract entries between 2  values.

it's kinda like this 
WHERE (attribute_id,value) IN ((5,'Yamaha Mate V50'),(6,'2012'), (7, between 200 and 600))

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. If you want to add another pair of values, just make it `3` in `count` comparison.